# Poetry add doesn't add nor install nor update .toml

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I run this on a Windows 10 64 bit system with Python 3.10 and Poetry 1.2.2:

```
...\Python\pyproj\pyActigraphy>poetry add pyActigraphy
Using version ^1.0 for pyactigraphy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)
```

... it doesn't actually do anything that I can see. It neither adds the dependency to the poetry.toml, nor does it install anything or update the lock file.

The same problem occurs when I try to install actipy.
Other dependencies like numpy work perfectly.

- Does anyone know, why it says Updating dependencies and Resolving dependencies but doesn't have any effect?
- Does anyone know a good workaround?

Many thanks and best regards!